# How to generate *.Designer.cs file from .resx on Mac?

Tags: macos, localization, visual-studio-mac, rider

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and Rider but none ot these tools is able to generate properties from .resx files. I found several answers related to resx generation on SO, but they don't help with my issue.

Is there any way to regenerate *.Designer.cs files on Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating code for resx files should work in Rider 2018.1. If it does not show lines with resource files from your project file. Something like < Content Include="MyResource.resx"...

Comment: I found that I can right click the resx file and select "Generate resources" but it doesn't change the corresponding Designer.cs file :/ Could you please guide me where should I put this "<Content Include=..."?

Comment: I installed the newest Rider 2018.1 EAP 181.4379.788 and resource generation finally works